# std::move of an object to a std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, class, c++11, templates, smart-pointers

Given the following templated class:

```
template<typename Container>
Class A
{
public:
    A() : {}

    bool push(std::shared_ptr<Container> container) 
    {
        ptr_vec.emplace_back(container)
    }

    void load(Container c) 
    {
        push(std::make_shared((Container)std::move(c));
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Container>> ptr_vec;
};
```

and the following code in `main.cpp`:

```
A<std::string> my_A {};
my_A.load("Hello");
```

I get the following error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'make_shared(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>)'
```

Can anyone shed some light regarding the error, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Your given code has a lot of typos.

However, if you fix those(here: https://godbolt.org/z/M81qnh), the error is coming from [`std::make_shared`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) function, which is a templated function. It needs the first argument to be explicitly specified

```
push(std::make_shared<Container>(std::move(c)));
//                   ^^^^^^^^^^
```